# Socket descriptor becomes invalid, connection remains open

Tags: c, sockets

I have two programs: a client (which just wraps the library that has problems) and an echo server. The client connects to the echo server, sends X bytes, and the echo server echoes them back.

When the client attempts to read from the socket (file) descriptor, a "bad file descriptor" error arises (EBADF).

For debugging purposes, before throwing the error on console with perror(), I tried to have the client attemp a write() like suggested in another question's answer, but the problem did persist.

**TL;DR: the socket descriptor is not being modified, the client can initially write() to the socket, but the same descriptor later becomes invalid. Why?**

The current code is available [here](http://pastebin.com/XJMPjFXK) (library, line 106), [here](http://pastebin.com/ff67UUyK) (executable using the library), and [here](http://pastebin.com/0MdcMqrx) (echo server, merely copypasted from the internet) - I'll add the useful parts of the code to the question as soon as an answer is provided.

Comment: Your "error" handling is invalid. Things can set errno to non-zero and not fail. You should only inspect errno if the function returned an error, your code doesn't do that properly.

Comment: That actually solves the question. I was checking for that kind of problem on the next read()s, but totally forgot to add that check on the first. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should have been:

```
int h;
r = 0;
while (r < 4 && (h = read(client->client_socket, buffer+r, 4 - r)) > 0)
{
    r += h;
}
if (h == -1)
    ...
```

Note that it is *never* correct to compare 'errno' to zero.

Answer (score -1):

As @Mat commented, I wasn't checking correctly whether read() was returning an error:
instead of

```
while (r < 4 && errno == 0)
{
    r += read(client->client_socket, buffer_length, 4 - r);
}
```

it should have been:

```
while (r < 4 && errno == 0)
{
    int h = read(client->client_socket, buffer_length, 4 - r);
    if (h == -1) { r = -1; break; }
    r += h;
}
```

and then when checking for errors:

```
if (r == -1)
{
    switch(errno)
    {
        case EBADF:
            //...
            break;
     }
}
```

since, as he said, read() can change errno even if it's successful.

Comment: It's still wrong. You **never** should inspect `errno` unless the function returned an error (`r<0`).

Comment: It actually checks for errors only if read() returns -1. The errno check is immediately after the while() loop.

Comment: No, this line is still wrong: `while (r < 4 && errno == 0)`. You should not be checking `errno == 0` when `r` is 0, 1, 2, or 3. And if `r<0`, `errno==0` is impossible anyway.